# JQuery // Remove Id character

Tags: jquery, replace, attributes

Trying to remove hashtag from the Id attr.

Html:

```
<div id="#First">1</div>
<div id="#Second">2</div>
<div id="#Third">3</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('[id^="#"]').attr('id').replace("#", "");
```

Comment: Can you remove the hash from the html itself? That is likely cleaner.

Comment: Not really:
In the DOM, it spitts out also to <a href="#First" ...   and where #First is created, the hashtag must be presented.

Comment: This should be resolved server-side, rather than forcing every client to undertake the same work on every page-load. Also, doing this client-side *probably* prevents linking to a specific element's `id`.

Comment: `$('[id^="#"]').hide();` is working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with the following jQuery snippet. I just changed a bit of your provided code.

```
$('[id^="#"]').each(function(){ // Loop through all selected divs
    this.id = this.id.replace('#', '');  // Replace Id
});
```

Quick demo:

The ID's get replaced and the CSS changes the color of the right ID's to green.

```js
$('[id^="#"]').each(function(){ // Loop through all inputs
    this.id = this.id.replace('#', '');  // Replace ID
});
```

```css
#First {
  color: green;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#Second {
  color: green;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#Third {
  color: green;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="#First">1</div>
<div id="#Second">2</div>
<div id="#Third">3</div>
```

Comment: You could also condense that to: `$('[id^="#"]').prop('id', function(index, current){ return current.replace('#', ''); });`

Answer (score 0):

Your question has become vague, I do not know exactly what you need, but this way you can get the ids individually without "#".

```
$( window ).on("load",
    function() {

        $("body").find('[id^="#"]').each(
            function(){
                var id = $(this).attr('id').replace("#", "");
                console.log(id);
                $(this).attr("id", id); // To change use this.
            }
        );      
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm quite fresh in the code world, but I try to get better. Because of you guys thats possible :) Thanks alot for all the help!

Comment: @Boggy keep going man, just try be more specific in your questions, to help us help you.